# D.va vs Brigitte. What is the strategy to defeat Brigitte as D.Va? (and vice versa)

Tags: overwatch

As D.Va, I've often come up against Brigitte and found myself lacking. I try to use my defense matrix to prevent her from striking me with her rocket flail, but she still gets me. What approach can I take to beat her?

How does Brigitte defeat D.va?

Comment: I haven't played much since Brigitte has been added but I'm almost sure that her rocket flail is a melee weapon similar to Reinhardt's. D.va's defense matrix only works on projectiles/bullets.

Answer (score 2):

In a straight up one on one, Brigitte is going to beat D.Va every time if you let Brigitte close to melee range:

- Brigitte's attacks are melee, which aren't blocked by Shield Matrix
- Brigitte can interrupt your micro missile attack or just block them with her shield
- Brigitte heals every time she hits you with melee.

However, as D.Va, you have a lot of mobility with your Jump Jets, so you can reach places Brigitte can't.  Once you do, you can shoot down her shield and she can only hit you with whip shot which is on a 4 second cooldown and requires that she drop her shield.

Comment: For that matter, Brigitte is one of the most powerful heroes... in melee range.  So, the best plan all around is to try to kill her (or at least break her shield) before she reaches melee range.  Breaking her shield also nullifies her stun attack.